# NiFi PutDatabaseRecord to Postgres

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql, virtual-machine, apache-nifi

I have NiFi installed on Windows.  On the same PC, I have a VirtualBox/Linux-based VM, on which I am running a Postgres database.  The ip for the VM is 192.168.1.X, the ip/port for the database is localhost:xxxx.

NiFi/PutSFTP can put files on the VM using the VM's host ip and default SFTP port.  NiFi/PutDatabaseRecord cannot insert records into the database using localhost.

Here is the question:  Given the information above, how do I set up NiFi/PutDatabaseRecord to insert data directly into the Postgres database?

Thanks,

John

Comment: I just found/learned about Linux UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) and opened up listening on the combination of the VM ip address and the database port number - this might make it easier for me to port forward to localhost:database port number - will test/add comment on this later.

Comment: Tested comment above, still more work to do.  If you have an answer, please post.

Answer (score 0):

Easy workarounds:

1. [Install Postgres for Windows](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/)
2. Install Docker on Windows and then run `docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -d postgres:latest`